# Comparing standard deviations of two unknown lists

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Consider the following problem:

- List A contains 15 numbers in the range from 10 to 50.
- List B contains 15 numbers in the range from -50 to -10.

Or any other two lists.

Is there some trick to compare the standard deviations of the two lists without even knowing what the actual numbers are?

Comment: Are the numbers uniformly drawn from those intervals?

Comment: Or even if they are integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Counterexample:

- The list (10, 10, 10, ..., 10) has the standard deviation 0.  The list (-50, -10, -50, -10, ..., -50) has a standard deviation of approximately 19.9555.
- The list (10, 50, 10, 50, ..., 10) has a standard deviation of approximately 19.9555.  The list (-10, -10, -10, ..., -10) has the standard deviation 0.

More generally, note that adding a constant value to all elements of a list does not change the standard deviation of the list.  Thus, as your intervals have the same length, for any list of numbers in the first interval, there is a list of numbers in the second interval with the same standard deviation, and vice versa.

Comment: if Average of first list is greater than that of second List then will the standard deviation would also be larger?

Comment: No, the standard deviation is not in any way linked to the average. In fact, the standard deviation is basically *defined* to be independent of the average -- the usual way of calculating it involves first normalizing the data by subtracting the average from all data points.